# (CKEDITOR) Internet Explorer remove resize handler

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, resize, ckeditor

I have the problem that on internet explorer for each div in the editor a resize box is shown.. This box isn´t shown for Mozilla Firefox. How can i remove this resize box/resize handler and focus the element directly on typing or selecting it?

Actually i need this: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-disableObjectResizing but it also needs to remove the weird box. If it isn't remove i need to click twice and the Ckeditor right click menu fails...

[image: Resize box?]

#### PArtial solution

This url provided a partial anwser
http://chris.photobooks.com/tests/rte/IE_resizing/IE_resizing.html

It is not something from CKEDITOR but from html5/javascript/ie
This is a temp fix for the right click menu to work ok, again.

```
    $("iframe")[0].contentDocument.attachEvent( 'oncontrolselect', function( event )
    {
            event.srcElement.focus();
            return false;
    });
```

To Test/reproduce the bug/problem:

```
<script src="http://ckeditor.com/apps/ckeditor/4.0.1/ckeditor.js"></script> 
<div id="testEditor">test text<div style="min-height:200px;"> test div</div></div> 
<script>CKEDITOR.replace("testEditor");</script>
```

Note: You need to click the div element to see the box.

Comment: See http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Disable-resize-handlers-IE This is kinda the same problem..

Comment: Seems like the attribute _cke_resizeable is set. I'm trying to remove it but didn't found a way yet.

Comment: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/1659 ?

Comment: It's not about the body element Ouadie, i have this problem with every block styled element.

Comment: can you put your code in `jsfiddle.net`?

Comment: I tried jsfiddle on multiple computer with internet explorer.. but that doesn't work so i don't see the need, but ok.. http://jsfiddle.net/AnMh4/ There is text normal and text with a div around it. In FF it will handle everything as text.. within Internet Explorer the box as shown in the post will show. This the behaviour that we don't like. And what i'am trying to remove.

Comment: I just tried this on **IE8** and it works without the box, `<script src="http://ckeditor.com/apps/ckeditor/4.0/ckeditor.js"></script>
<div id="testEditor">test text<div> test div</div></div>
<script>CKEDITOR.replace("testEditor");</script>` which version of IE do you have?

Comment: Updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AnMh4/1/ I found out that it has something to do with certain css styles. Min-width, min-height soon i will give more examples.

Comment: try it with `style="min-heigth: 100px;"` works fine on **IE10**

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't work fine in IE7, IE8 and IE9. I'm sorry i thought all IE did have the problem.. but apparently not..

Comment: @Ouadie, I just checked it again in IE10 and the problem does exists in all versions of IE.. Check the source if the min-height is placed. .. Also i did the check the jsfiddle, but there the problem doesn't show.. So i prefer that you past the code that i placed in the main topic in a html file.

Comment: yes I created a `.html` containing `<script src="http://ckeditor.com/apps/ckeditor/4.0/ckeditor.js"></script><div id="testEditor">test text<div style="min-heigth: 100px;"> test div</div></div><script>CKEDITOR.replace("testEditor");</script>` and no box on **IE10** neither **IE8**

Comment: And if you open the source after loading the coeditor, you see the div with the style? Notice also that i use 4.0.1.. See Main post. (Don't think it maters)

Comment: @spons  if i remember right this problem will appear as soon as the div has the `hasLayout` property set (as you have already found out it is caused by different css properties: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/haslayout). you can only get rid of this if you remove the css property that is the reason for this box. i'm pretty sure newer IE will display this when IE is in compatibility mode. but if it appears you can't remove it with javascript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like IE automatically adds resize handles on editable elements with defined dimensions. If you get rid of the min-height, the handles will go away.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <!-- IE9 displays resize handles around this div because
         its height is defined. -->
    <div style="height: 100px">test</div>
</div>

<div contenteditable="true">
    <!-- No resize handles here because size is auto. -->
    <div>test</div>
</div>

<div>
    <!-- Obviously no handles here either because content is
         not editable. -->
    <div style="height: 100px">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand that this solves the problem. But it isn't the solution to my problem. because i can't remove the height.. i don't control them. I need to remove the handler if a height is defined.

Comment: Finally i defined a css to overwrite all the css that is causing the problem. tnx for the feedback. Kinda sad that it isn't removable

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't show the boxes when the editable element is contained in a not editable element:

```
<div contenteditable="false">
    <div contenteditable="true">
       . . .
    </div>
</div>
```

The ckeditor content is edited in an HTML document. The contenteditable flag is set by ckeditor on the body tag of that document. It seems not possible to set a contenteditable=false attribute to its parent, the HTML tag.

My (jQuery) workaround is to set the iframe body contenteditable attribute to false, and wrap the body content in a div that has contenteditable=true. You will have to do that on every mode change, but the mode event is also thrown on instanceReady:

```
editor.on('mode', function (evt) {
   //-- in system mode return, editor has no document here
   if (!evt.editor.document) return false;

   //-- get the body of the document in the cdeditor iframe
   var $editorDocumentBody = $(evt.editor.document.getBody().$);

   //-- if ie hasLayout property, wrapper needed to avoid resize borders
   var documentStyle = $editorDocumentBody[0].currentStyle;
   if (typeof documentStyle.hasLayout != 'undefined' && documentStyle.hasLayout){

      //-- check if wrapper div already exists
      var $insertedElement = $editorDocumentBody.find('div[contenteditable="true"]');

      //-- if not, create wrapper, append body content to it, append to body
      if (!$insertedElement.length) {
         $insertedElement = $('<div/>', {
            contenteditable: 'true'
         }).append($editorDocumentBody.contents()).appendTo($editorDocumentBody);
      };

      //-- set the contenteditable attributes
      $editorDocumentBody.attr('contenteditable', 'false');
      $insertedElement.attr('contenteditable', 'true');
   };
}
```

You might need to allow elements with the contenteditable attribute. You can edit config.js and add something like this:

```
config.allowedContent = 
   'span p a img hr h6 h5 h4 h3 h2 h1 th td tr div;*[contenteditable]';
```

Please note that this workaround wraps a div around the user content, what might not be preferable. You can see the div with the contenteditable attribute in HTML mode.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had a problem removing the resize handler in IE11 in the [Summernote](https://summernote.org) WYSIWYG-editor. I also reviewed many topics on **Stackoverflow**. The reason was that I had the property **width: 705px** in the styles for paragraph p. When I removed this property, then the damn resize handler disappeared!